# spring-boot-starter-amqp dependency causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, rabbitmq

I have a basic Spring Boot project where I try to implement simple messaging with RabbitMQ. When I add **spring-boot-starter-amqp** dependency into my `pom.xml` file and start spring boot application, I get `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` exception caused by `java.lang.StackOverflowError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:280)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:63)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:63)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rabbitmq.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>rabbitmqFstClient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>rabbitmqFstClient</name>
    <description>Spring-Boot rabbitmq client</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

If I remove **spring-boot-starter-amqp** dependency from pom.xml, the project works without errors:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that it will solve your problem but you have anyway a potential conflict since according to log you pull the log4J dependency.
If you do it, you have to exclude logback that is provided by default when you you declare :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

You can check it by displaying the dependency tree of you project and by looking what the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar` dependency pulls:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | | +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | | | +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] | | | | +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] | | | | \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] | | | +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] | | | +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] | | | \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
```

[Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) states that it supports Log4j 2 for logging configuration if it is on the classpath. If you are using the starters for assembling dependencies that means you have to exclude Logback and then include log4j 2 instead.

So to use only log4j, you could exclude Logback from spring-boot-starter-web dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Or to use only logback, you should exclude the log4j probably pulled by one of your other declared dependencies. 
Use : `mvn dependency:tree` from the Maven project to know the culprit.

But in any case, you should not use both.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to use AMQP via RabbitMQ, then remove all of the JMS dependencies.

Also, for a simple application you don't need Spring Integration either.  Try your application using only **spring-boot-starter-amqp**